Questions about definition of admissible ordering for monomials.
Background
Definition  We will introduce an order relation $\prec$ on $\mathfrak{M}$.  We define $\prec$ to be an admissible order relation on $\mathfrak{M}$ if it is a total order which is compatible with the multiplication of monomials, i.e.,
$(1)$ For any paire of monomials $m,n$ we have $m\prec n$ or $n\prec m$ or $m=n$
$(2)$ if $m_1\prec m_2$ and $m_2\prec m_3$ then $m_1\prec m_3$
$(3)$ $1\prec m$ for any monomial $m\neq 1$
$(4)$ if $m_1\prec m_2$ then $mm_1\prec mm_2$ for any monomial $m$
Questions
For the above Definition, when it define "admissible" ordering for order relation on $\mathfrak{M}$, $\prec$ must be a total order, and satisfies the critierias $(1)-(4)$.  But,
$1.$ why does it stipulates that the total order is "compatible" with the mulitplication of monomials.  I thought being a "total" order for an order relations means any two elements within an order relation is comparable, so is it referring to criterias $(3), (4)$ above?
$2.$ for $(3)$ the element $1$ is the identity element, and the condition $1\prec m$ means that for any monomial $m\in \mathfrak{M}, m=x_1^{c_1}\cdots x_k^{c_k}$, all exponents $c_j\geq 1$ in $x_j^{c_j}$? Actually, if $m\neq 1$, why is $1\prec m$ necessary?  In some other books that I have consulted, criteria $(3)$ is not even mentioned.  But those sources did mention about the notion of well foundedness or well ordering in relation to admisible ordering. I am not sure why there are such differences for listing criterias for admissible ordering.
Thank you in advance.

"i.e.": The conditions (1) through (4) are an elaboration or clarification of what the phrase "total order which is compatible with the multiplication of monomials" means.

@DanielSchepler I am still confused about $(3)$, if $m \neq 1$, then isn't $1\prec m$ redundant?  I mean $m \neq 1$ ensures the case $x_1^0\cdots x_n^0$ don't ever occur.  Am I correct?

Without that condition, you could instead have $m \prec 1$.

@DanielSchepler $m\neq 1$ implies $1\prec m$?  If so, isn't it better to rephrase it that way. I think in another text on computational methods for physicsts, that condition was stated in english as "a constant is the smallest monomial:  $x^\alpha \succ, 1$ for all $x^\alpha \neq 1$."
